# Filter multiple columns based on two criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google

So I have this 2 columns:

```
B  (white background)   A (white background)
A  (white background)   B (green background)
C  (green background)   C (green background)
```

And I would like to make a function where I sort it as follows:

```
C (green background)   B (green background)
A (white background)   C (green background)
B (white background)   A (white background)
```

So this sorting does the following Automatically:

- Sort from A-Z
- Also sort the green background colored cells ABOVE the white colored cells.

Atm I have this: =Sort(B2:B1300,1,TRUE) which only sorts from A-Z.
Filters dont work because I want it to change automatically changes automatically. Also the two columns dont have matching colors row-wise. So that is also something I am bumping into.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You've got it backwards, you want to sort by color, then by alphabet.  Not alphabet then color.  Edit your question.

Comment: Please explain what this means: *Also the two columns dont have matching colors row-wise. So that is also something I am bumping into.*